# How to call javascript function in PHP Scriptable Web Browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, click, browser

I am using PHP Scriptable Web Browser to download some data from one website.

and there is form we have to set values to fields and then click on GO! button it will call java script function so i am not getting how to call javascript function in PHP Scriptable Web Browser.

```
  <input name="order_date_from" size="10" maxlength="10" value="10/24/2013">
        To Date:
        <input name="order_date_to" size="10" maxlength="10" value="10/24/2013">

        Date Type:
        <select name="date_type" id="date_type">
            <option value="ORIG_ORD_DATE">Orig Ord Date</option>
            <option value="MLM_ORD_DATE">Mlm Ord Date</option>
            <option value="DATE_SHIP">Ship Date</option>
            <option value="RMA_DATE">RMA Date</option>
            <option value="RETURN_DATE">Return Date</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="GO!" style="width:60px;" id="submit_form" onclick="doSubmit()">
```

Then using  PHP Scriptable Web Browser i set those values using

```
$browser->setFieldByName('order_date_from', '10/21/2013');
$browser->setFieldByName('order_date_to', '10/21/2013');
$browser->setFieldById('date_type', 'RETURN_DATE');
```

after that

```
$log1=$browser->click('GO!');
```

$log1 should contains the resultant webpage but its not showing anything can any tell me how to call javascript function which is dosumbit() in this case.

refered link http://www.simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html

Thank you 
Gajanan Hiroji

Answer (score 0):

> The browser emulation offered by SimpleTest mimics the actions which can be perform by a user on a standard HTML page. Javascript is not supported, and it's unlikely that support will be added any time soon.

— http://www.simpletest.org/en/form_testing_documentation.html

So you can't.

Either reverse engineer the JS yourself and then repeat whatever it does in your code or use a a scriptable browsers that supports JS (such as Selenium or PhantomJS).

Comment: Can you tell me when i $log1=$browser->click('GO!'); do this will it call dosumbit() function from javascript?

Comment: No, of course it won't. To repeat part of my answer: **Javascript is not supported**

Comment: Ok fine thank you for your ans. i will try to make use of your link which you have sent in last post.

Comment: The relevant information from that link is quoted in the answer. You can't use the tool you are using to run JS. You either need to do something other than running JS or change tools.

Comment: Ok fine can you please tell us which is best to extract data from website either Selenium or PhantomJ with reference link?

Comment: Their homepages are very easy to find with DuckDuckGo/Google/etc. I don't have a strong preference for either one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I found the alternative way to get the result from one url passing parameters .dosubmit() function was calling internally this url with parameter so used post() method to get the data.

here is code

```
    $parameters = array (
    "group_code" => "xxxx",
    "selClNo" => "xxxx",
    "navigator" => "xxxxxx",
    );

    $data=$browser->post('https://www.xxxx.com/modules.php?m=charts&option=returns',$parameters);
    echo $data
```